# Having trouble with Combobox.removeAllItems(); method

Tags: java, swing, combobox

I hope my problem is really basic but it is driving me crazy :(

I have uploaded a video of the problem in action
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dd8Qg5DFMpg&feature=youtu.be

I am using a jXDatePicker to pick a date, and add a list of employee Id's in a combobox. First Time, the code runs smoothly. However, when I choose the date second time on the jXDatePicker, it throws a null pointer exception. Third time around code is again working fine but the employee names are not being populated in the textbox, when I choose a value from the combobox. Strangely employeeIds in the combobox are being populated fine. I have traced the problem to removeallitems() combobox line below, because when I remove this line, it does not throw a null pointer exception.

Below are the codes for action events of datepicker and combobox.
combobox is named empbx.

```
private void jXDatePicker1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)    {                                              
    // TODO add your handling code here:

    empbx.removeAllItems();/////THIS LINE OVER HERE
    d = jXDatePicker1.getDate();
          emp1=ControllerClass.searchEmpAvalibility(String.valueOf(d.getDay()));


    for (Employee e : emp1) {
        if (e != null) {


                empbx.addItem(e.getEmployeeId());

        }
    }
    //unrelated code
    //TableClean();
    //TableuncheckEmp();
    //TableFill();

}

private void empbxActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    emp=ControllerClass.getEmployees();
    Object s = empbx.getSelectedItem();
    for (Employee e : emp) {
        if (e != null) {
            if (Integer.parseInt(s.toString()) == e.getEmployeeId()) {
                empftxt.setText(e.getFirstName());
                empltxt.setText(e.getLastName());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Error log:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at newnapit.ScheduleGUI.empbxActionPerformed(ScheduleGUI.java:855)
    at newnapit.ScheduleGUI.access$800(ScheduleGUI.java:42)
    at newnapit.ScheduleGUI$9.actionPerformed(ScheduleGUI.java:407)
    at javax.swing.JComboBox.fireActionEvent(JComboBox.java:1258)
    at javax.swing.JComboBox.contentsChanged(JComboBox.java:1331)
    at javax.swing.JComboBox.intervalRemoved(JComboBox.java:1351)
    at javax.swing.AbstractListModel.fireIntervalRemoved(AbstractListModel.java:179)
    at javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel.removeAllElements(DefaultComboBoxModel.java:174)
    at javax.swing.JComboBox.removeAllItems(JComboBox.java:771)
    at newnapit.ScheduleGUI.jXDatePicker1ActionPerformed(ScheduleGUI.java:830)
    at newnapit.ScheduleGUI.access$900(ScheduleGUI.java:42)
    at newnapit.ScheduleGUI$10.actionPerformed(ScheduleGUI.java:415)
    at org.jdesktop.swingx.JXDatePicker.fireActionPerformed(JXDatePicker.java:911)
    at org.jdesktop.swingx.JXDatePicker.commitEdit(JXDatePicker.java:740)
    at org.jdesktop.swingx.plaf.basic.BasicDatePickerUI.commit(BasicDatePickerUI.java:914)
    at org.jdesktop.swingx.plaf.basic.BasicDatePickerUI$Handler.monthViewActionPerformed(BasicDatePickerUI.java:1504)
    at org.jdesktop.swingx.plaf.basic.BasicDatePickerUI$Handler.actionPerformed(BasicDatePickerUI.java:1479)
    at org.jdesktop.swingx.JXMonthView.fireActionPerformed(JXMonthView.java:1845)
    at org.jdesktop.swingx.JXMonthView.commitSelection(JXMonthView.java:1732)
    at org.jdesktop.swingx.plaf.basic.BasicMonthViewUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicMonthViewUI.java:1753)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:746)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:719)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:717)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:716)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: Runnable example please...

Comment: The only reason you might get a NPE at the specified line is if the empbx was null

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot post a picture here, unless I have 10 of something.

Comment: The stack trace says that the exception is thown at line 855, in the method `empbxActionPerformed`. What is this line?

Comment: @JB Nizet, Hey thanks! It was this line in empbx action method: if (Integer.parseInt(s.toString()) == e.getEmployeeId())..... I changed the code and it is working fine

Comment: private void empbxActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
               String ss="0";
        emp=ControllerClass.getEmployees();
        Object s = empbx.getSelectedItem();
        if(s!=null) {ss=s.toString();}
       
        for (Employee e : emp) {
            if (e != null) {
                if (Integer.parseInt(ss)==e.getEmployeeId()) {
                    empftxt.setText(e.getFirstName());
                    empltxt.setText(e.getLastName());
                }
            }
        }
    }

Comment: So, given that this line can not be executed if `e` is null, the only possible remaining reason is that `s` is null. Check it's not null before using it. Coming to this diagnostic is extremely easy if you just read the stack trace. It's even easier if you use a debugger. Learn to do that.

Comment: Thank you again, I will definitely keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you use DefaultComboBoxModel and use removeAllElements() method that would be work fine.
you may try using this code

```
 DefaultComboBoxModel d=(DefaultComboBoxModel) jComboBox1.getModel();
 d.removeAllElements();
```

Hope this is helps

Comment: Sorry I am new to programming, is it the same if I use this customize code on Netbeans and type this out: empbx = new javax.swing.JComboBox(new DefaultComboBoxModel());

Comment: No that is not the same. In your case combo box initialize like follows.                       JComboBox jComboBox1 = new javax.swing.JComboBox(new DefaultComboBoxModel());  and that's not contains the removeAllElements method.  try with the    DefaultComboBoxModel and removeAllElements()

Comment: Sorry it is not working :( I have uploaded a video of the code running at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dd8Qg5DFMpg&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I have a mental capacity of a two year old. It was not the remove all items method that was causing the problem. The problem was casting Object s, as pointed out by @JB Nizet.

```
private void empbxActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
// TODO add your handling code here:
emp=ControllerClass.getEmployees();
Object s = empbx.getSelectedItem();
for (Employee e : emp) {
    if (e != null) {
        if (Integer.parseInt(s.toString()) == e.getEmployeeId()) {//This line over here
            empftxt.setText(e.getFirstName());
            empltxt.setText(e.getLastName());
        }
    }
}
```

}

So I changed it to:

```
private void empbxActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    String ss="0";
    emp=ControllerClass.getEmployees();
    Object s = empbx.getSelectedItem();
    if(s!=null) {ss=s.toString();}
    //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Information");
    for (Employee e : emp) {
        if (e != null) {
            if (Integer.parseInt(ss)==e.getEmployeeId()) {
                empftxt.setText(e.getFirstName());
                empltxt.setText(e.getLastName());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And now it is working fine. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

```
//This solution fills the JComboBox only with values passed in array.

public void fillComboBox(JComboBox<T> cb, T[] values) {
        cb.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<>(values));
}
```